# Xcode 10, Swift 4 - Move functions to separate file?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created my first swift app and want to organize my code a bit.
First, I'd like to move my functions to a separate file called functions.swift, but that gets me into trouble, with the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'myLabel'
```

My example code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    func myFunction(){
        myLabel.stringValue="Hello World"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
        myFunction()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to move to a separate file:

```
    func myFunction(){
        myLabel.stringValue="Hello World"
    }
```

The error is "sort of" understandable for me, but not how to solve it.

What is the proper way of organizing functions and other stuff in separate files and then include or call them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a global "functions.swift" is not a good way to organize your code. `myFunction` here is a method that belongs to `ViewController`. It's not a free-function (i.e. a function that belongs to no type), so grouping it with "functions" would be very confusing.

If your `ViewController.swift` becomes unwieldy, first you should ask whether it's doing too much and you need to create another type (not just a generic "functions" file). But if it just needs to be broken up a bit, the right way is to create a file just for this portion of `ViewController` as an extension, generally in a file with a name like `Type+Section.swift` where "Type" is the type (like `ViewController` and "Section" is the category of extensions (like `Drawing`).

```
extension ViewController {
    func myFunction(){
        myLabel.stringValue="Hello World"
    }
}
```

As a rule, though, especially if you're a beginner, there is seldom a reason to do this. Splitting up the type into multiple files is more likely to create confusion than to make things clear.

Comment: I have a small iPhone and tvOS app in a single project. They both use a single set of functions. How can I keep the code for those functions in a single file and have both Groups (iOS app and tvOS app) access it?

Comment: @Ryan By putting the functions in one or more files (appropriate to what they're for), and making those files part of the appropriate targets. If you're having specific problems with that, you should open a new question with details of your issues.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Napier. Working on it. Mostly working now.